# Return Image from Next.JS API & Display In Browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, next.js, next.js13

I'd like to make requests to my own next.js endpoints and return an image that I can then embed into my website. The problem right now seems to me that the image is being "downloaded"straightaway - it does not stay in the browser window.

```
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (_req: NextRequest) => {

  const res = await fetch("https://picsum.photos/200/300");
  const blob = await res.blob();

  const headers = new Headers();

  headers.set("Content-Type", "image/*");
  
  return new NextResponse(blob, { status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers });
};
```

How can I achieve it with next.js, that the image that's being returned from the API is being rendered in the browser (just like going to a url like [www.mywebsite.com/myphoto.png](http://www.mywebsite.com/myphoto.png))

Answer (score 1):

You can return the image (blob) as b64 encoded, and then display it in the browser.

your API

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const img = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/example.jpeg");
    const blob = await img.blob();
    const text = await blob.arrayBuffer();
    res.setHeader("content-Type", "text/plain");
    const encoded = Buffer.from(text).toString("base64");
    res.send(encoded);
}
```

your Page

```
"use client"

import {useState} from "react";

export default function Page() {
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const displayImage = async () => {
        setImage(await fetch('/api/download').then((res) => res.text()));
    }
  return (<>
      <button onClick={displayImage}>Display image</button>
        {image && <img src={`data:image/jpeg;base64, ${image}`} />}
  </>)
}
```

Comment: thanks. that's not what i want to do though. i want to return the image directly from my API (similar to a service like cloudinary or imgix).